# MapReduce ArrayList Type Mismatch

Tags: java, hadoop, arraylist, mapreduce

Hi I'm one week old in Hadoop and experimenting with it.

I have the following input values as CSV.

```
    PRAVEEN,400201399,Baby,026A1K,12/04/2010
    PRAVEEN,4002013410,TOY,02038L,1/04/2014
    PRAVEEN,2727272727272,abc,03383,03/14/2015
    PRAVEEN,2263637373,cde,7373737,12/24/2012
```

The Map function should pick 2nd value from the CSV as key (ie 400201399 and so on) and 3rd and last  of the values as VALUE(for eg TOY and 12/04/2010), I want to put the Values inside an ArrayList rather than as Text.

But I'm getting the following error -

```
    Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in value from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received java.util.ArrayList
```

The Reduce function is also very simple , I have to traverse through the list and get the desired result as the final values (In the reduce code below I'm picking only the date from the list)

Here is my code -

```
    package com.test.mapreduce;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Set;

    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;
    import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
    import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;



 public class RetailCustomerProduct extends Configured implements Tool {

 public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase
 implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, List<Text> > {

      private Text key1 = new Text();
      private List<Text> productList = new ArrayList<Text>();
      private Text value1 = new Text();
      private Text product = new Text();
      private int noofFields = 5;



       public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
                 OutputCollector<Text, List<Text>> output,
                 Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        String line = value.toString().replaceAll("\\s+","");
        String[] split = line.split(",");


        if(split.length!=noofFields){
        return;
        }

        else {
            key1.set((split[1])); 
            value1.set(split[4].toString().trim());
            product.set(split[2].toString().trim());
            productList.add(value1);
            productList.add(product);


            System.out.println(split[4].toString().trim());
            output.collect(key1, productList);
     }
    }
  }

 public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, List<Text>, Text,      Text> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<List<Text>> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            Date date = new Date();

            List<String> dateList = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> productList = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(Iterator<List<Text>> it = values; it.hasNext();) {
                // add the values in the arrayList
                dateList.add(((Text)it.next().get(0)).toString());
                productList.add(((Text)it.next().get(1)).toString());
                }

            if(dateList.size()==1){ 

                try  {
                    date = formatter.parse(dateList.get(0).toString());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }  
            else {
                String str = dateList.get(0).toString();
                try {

                    date = formatter.parse(dateList.get(0).toString());

                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                for(int i=0 ; i <dateList.size();++i){
                    try {

                        if((formatter.parse(dateList.get(i).toString())).compareTo(date)>0){
                            date=formatter.parse(dateList.get(i).toString());
                            // getting the max date from the list
                        }
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } 
            }    

            Text value = new Text(date.toString());
            output.collect(key, value);
        }
    }



 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
 Configuration conf = getConf();

 JobConf job = new JobConf(conf, RetailCustomerProduct.class);

 Path in = new Path(args[0]);
 Path out = new Path(args[1]);
 FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

 job.setJobName("RetailCustomerProduct");
 job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
 job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

 job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
 job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

 job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
 job.set("key.value.separator.in.input.line", ",");

 JobClient.runJob(job);

 return 0;
}

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
 int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new RetailCustomerProduct(), args);

 System.exit(res);
 }

}
```

Is there any different ArrayList Implementation in hadoop ?

My Map function should take Longwritable as KEY and Text as VALUE , and should output Text as KEY and ArrayList as VALUE.

My Reduce function should accept Text as KEY and ArrayList as Value and then output Text as KEY and Text as VALUE.

So In the driver class , which classes has to be Included , currently its like this.

```
 job.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
 job.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

 job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

Please can anyone help  with the correct code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am new to Hadoop too. But I think this line is the problem:

```
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
```

This sets the output type to `Text`, not `List<Text>`. 
I have not tried to output lists. Instead, I build a tab-delimited string from the list and output it as an instance of Text.

```
new Text(split[4].toString().trim() + "\t" + split[2].toString().trim());
```

Comment: Hi ahoffer thanks for the Input , yes you are right , the problem is with                                     job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);                               but its not accepting                job.setOutputValueClass(ArrayList.class);                             and the solution that you have provided will work, But juss for the heck of it, I wanted to do it with an arraylist